# ¿Cómo centrar texto en lenguaje ZPL?

Tags: zebra, zpl

Tengo el siguiente código el cual imprimo una etiqueta con la información de un producto. Pero tengo el problema que el nombre del producto no se centra. Me pasa que si el nombre es muy largo se sale de los límites de la etiqueta y no aparece. Lo que quiero es que el nombre parta del centro y se vaya ampliando a lo largo de la etiqueta y si excede los límites que siga escribiendo en la siguiente línea. Agradecería cualquier ayuda

```
    ^XA
   ^CF0,30
  ^FO150,30^FDNombre del Producto^FS
  ^CF0,60
  ^FO200,90^FDPrecio^FS
 ^FX Third section with bar code.
  ^BY2,2,50
  ^FO170,180^BC^FD1234789^FS
 ^XZ
```

Comment: Utilice el comando `^FB` Field Block. Define el ancho y alto máximos que se representará en el texto, más la alineación.

Comment: Había dejado esa parte pendiente, hasta ahorita la remoto. Pero no logro hacer que me quede bien. Como sería la forma para que el comando FB funcione? Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Cuáles son las dimensiones de la etiqueta y cuánto espacio desea asignar para que el texto se ajuste? ¿Puede publicar una imagen de una etiqueta donde el texto se ha desbordado y se ha recortado?

Answer (score 0):

**NOTA:** Esto solo funciona si se está utilizando puntos como unidad de medida (esta es la predeterminada pero se especifica como `^MUden` en el ejemplo a continuación). Si se usa mm (`^MUm`), el elemento central **NO** funciona correctamente (probado en labelary.com y Zebra S4m).

Use `^FB` para definir un bloque de campo. Segun el manual:

> El comando `^FB` le permite imprimir texto en un formato de tipo de
> bloque definido. Este comando da formato a una cadena `^FD` o `^SN` en
> un bloque de texto utilizando el origen, la fuente y la rotación
> especificados para la cadena de texto. El comando `^FB` también
> contiene una función automática de ajuste de palabras.

Puede ver este [ejemplo](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&quality=grayscale&width=2.6&height=2.6&units=inches&index=0&rotation=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5EMUd%0A%5ELH10%2C10%0A%5ECF0%2C50%0A%5EGB500%2C500%2C10%5EFS%0A%5EFO0%2C50%20%20%5EFDNormal%5EFS%0A%5EFO0%2C150%20%5EFB500%2C%2C%2CL%20%5EFDLeft%5EFS%0A%5EFO0%2C250%20%5EFB500%2C%2C%2CC%20%5EFDCenter%5EFS%0A%5EFO0%2C350%20%5EFB500%2C%2C%2CR%20%5EFDRight%5EFS%0A%5EXZ) realizado en [labelary.com](http://labelary.com/) o probarlo con el siguiente codigo:

```
^XA
^MUd
^LH10,10
^CF0,50
^GB500,500,10^FS
^FO0,50  ^FDNormal^FS
^FO0,150 ^FB500,,,L ^FDLeft^FS
^FO0,250 ^FB500,,,C ^FDCenter^FS
^FO0,350 ^FB500,,,R ^FDRight^FS
^XZ
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]